# Minimum Concrete Thickness Over PVC After Rough-In

Tags: plumbing, concrete, basement, pvc, rough-in

I just has some plumbing roughed in for my basement. The plumber did an okay job but for some reason routed the drain pipe for the sink under the area where my shower will go. This would't normally be a problem but he left the pipe a little high (perhaps he needed to in order to get the required slope) where he connected it from the wall to where it would run through the trench I chipped thought the concrete slab.

Since I have a really low basement (6'7" floor to joist) inches matter for the shower. I was wondering what is the minimum thickness for the concrete to cover the PVC. It should be stated the base I have has little pieces of plywood at the four corners and one of these corners would be sitting directly on the pipe (assuming I can't remove them).

Any help would be great as I don't want the floor to crack or to damage the pipe but I also need to save as much space as possible.

Comment: What kind of shower pan are you going to use? I have laid tile within 1/2" of plumbing and had no problems with cracking.

Comment: IMO If concrete will get underneath the pipe it will be well supported and also the slab can be thick enough to avoid problems. I don't think a relatively slight contact with the pipe from the shower base would be catastrophic, PVC pipe is pretty tough. But a large 'hump' of pipe sticking out could be liable to get damaged/ cracked.